# Driving in Tree Unity 3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys i'm trying to drive in the my GameObject (The Player) in my Project, I want a script to navigate to a var in a script that is on another GameObject. It's not easy because there is Parents and children... Here is my tree:

```
>PlayerEntity
    >Canvas
        Gun_Name_Text
        Gun_Ammo_Text
    >Player
        Sprite
```

I want a script attached to 'Gun_Name_Text' to fetch a var in a script attached to 'Player', so i didnt manage to do it with :

```
var ammo1 = GetComponentInParent<GameObject> ().GetComponent<weapon> ().weaponOn.Ammo1;
```

PS: I prefer not to use GameObject.Find()
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you not just assign it in the inspector?

Comment: aaaaaah smart one ;) didnt think about it

Comment: I answered with how you could do it through code if you want to. Bear in mind that you would be better off getting a reference to the `weapon` script and then modifying the `Ammo1` value with that reference. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the easiest way to do this would to be to just assign the variable in the inspector. However if you can't do this then you could simply use:

```
OtherScript otherScript = null;

void Start()
{
    otherScript = transform.root.GetComponentInChildren<OtherScript>();
}
```

Note: This will set `otherScript` equal to the first instance of the `OtherScript` that it finds in the child objects though. You will have to use `GetComponentsInChildren` if you have more than one `OtherScript` object in the children.

For your specific example you could use:

```
var ammo1 = transform.root.GetComponentInChildren<weapon>().Ammo1;
```

If you are calling this often then it would be wise to cache a refrence to the `weapon` script though. You will also have to do this if you want to modify the `Ammo1` variable that is a member of the `weapon` class as it is passed to the `var ammo1` by value and not by reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just want to display it

Comment: Ace, all cool then. Remember and accept if this is the answer!

Comment: hi @Ay0m3 you need to TICK an answer, this is important as you are a new user. otherwise you will get moderated and never be able to do anything easily on here

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where my game object does not know everything that interacts with it. An example would be a destructible object. If I wanted to know so what I'm hitting that was destructible I'd have all destructible objects inherit from a base type or interface and search on that type. Here is an example:

```
private void CheckForDestructables(Collider2D c)
{
  this.Print("CheckForDestructables Called");
  string attackName = GetCurrentAttackName();
  AttackParams currentAttack = GetCurrentAttack(attackName);
  D.assert(currentAttack != null);
  this.Print("CheckForDestructables Called");

  if (currentAttack.IsAttacking && c.gameObject.tag == "Destructable")
  {
    List<BaseDestructibleScript> s = c.GetComponents<BaseDestructibleScript>().ToList();

    D.assert(s.Any(), "Could Not find child of type BaseDestructibleScript");

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Count(); i++)
    {
      s[i].onCollision(Movement.gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```